# Navigation property issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, code-first

I've created a [ChessLibrary](https://github.com/Youssef1313/ChessSharp) in C# and tested it on a WinForms project.

Now, I'm trying to make a website using ASP.NET MVC, EF code-first to consume this library.

I've created a `Game` model in my asp.net mvc project with the following properties:

```cs
using ChessLibrary;

namespace ChessWebsite.Models
{
    public class Game
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser WhitePlayer { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser BlackPlayer { get; set; }
        public GameBoard GameBoard { get; set; }

    }
}
```

when I try to `Add-Migration`, I get the following error:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

ChessWebsite.Models.GameBoard: : EntityType 'GameBoard' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
ChessWebsite.Models.Move: : EntityType 'Move' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
GameBoards: EntityType: EntitySet 'GameBoards' is based on type 'GameBoard' that has no keys defined.
Moves: EntityType: EntitySet 'Moves' is based on type 'Move' that has no keys defined.
```

My `GameBoard` class has the following properties:

```cs
public List<Move> Moves { get; set; }
public Piece[,] Board { get; set; }

public GameState GameState { get; private set; }
public bool CanWhiteCastleKingSide { get; private set; } = true;
public bool CanWhiteCastleQueenSide { get; private set; } = true;
public bool CanBlackCastleKingSide { get; private set; } = true;
public bool CanBlackCastleQueenSide { get; private set; } = true;
```

I'm not sure if there is a simple solution, or I've a design problem from the beginning ?

This question has been asked before, but the solutions was about adding `[Key]` attribute to `EntityType` in the error. but I don't need a key for `Move` or `GameBoard`.

Comment: If you want to store the moves they do need a key and they should be a collection of `Game`. Then `GameBoard` could be a complex type.

Comment: Show me how you map the relationship of your entities. also, the Gameboard entity doesn't have an id.

Comment: The ChessLibrary project itself doesn't require having an id, so assume that the library is just a blackbox that I don't have access to.
I want the solution to be something inside the asp mvc project.

Comment: @Valkyrie, besides the default identity in mvc, I've only one `DbSet<Game>` only.
The GameBoard class is part of the library, I've referencing this library to my mvc project. as I said in the previous comment, The library don't need Id for GameBoard.
Also, each `Game` should be related to only one `GameBoard`
so why I would have an Id for GameBoard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> each Game should be related to only one GameBoard so why I would have an Id for GameBoard

This is the key question.  In memory an object doesn't need an ID.  But if you want to save the object to a database and retrieve it later it has to have a key property.

You should probably serialize the game state to a JSON document and store and retrieve that, instead of mapping each class to a separate database table.  In EF Core you can use a [Value Conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) to store and retrieve the entire GameBoard in a single column as JSON.  See eg https://github.com/Innofactor/EfCoreJsonValueConverter, or just serialize it yourself in string property of some entity.

Comment: I'm not using .NET Core, but the JSON serialization idea seems good to me :)
Thanks!

Comment: @david-browne-microsoft I got a problem in serialization, my GameBoard has a variable `Board` that is 2D array of `Piece`.
Piece is an abstract class, there are sub-classes derives from it like Rook, Bishop, etc..
so the serialized string didn't have any indication about the actual piece.
I could fix that by adding:
`public string PieceName => this.GetType().Name;`
to the abstract class.
but, will that later cause problems when trying to deserialize ? is there a better approach.

Comment: Using
`var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = All };`
fixes my problem in last comment.